# bootstrap menu top affix

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a bootstrap menu with an image and under the menu links, that when it's scrolled the menu sticks on the top of the window.

I've found interesting bootstrap affix and have used what's in this thread:
[bootstrap-affix : Div underneath affix "jumps" to top. How do I make it smoothly scroll behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540969/bootstrap-affix-div-underneath-affix-jumps-to-top-how-do-i-make-it-smoothly)

The problem is that when I press the menu's button the options are under the content text of the page.

I've written a fiddle for you to see my problem and try a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/mram888/WnPqF/

I've tried to put different z-index for the class of my menu divs, but only works properly when the page is scrolled and the menu is affixed on the top.

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:2;
}

#nav > .navbar-inner {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to apply the `z-index` to the `#nav` not the .nav-wrapper:

```
#nav { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; 
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/t7pL3/

Answer (score 7):

Another variation for you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/6P5sF/

The behaviour here is slightly different than before. The navbar scrolls with the page before it is affixed, and when the collapsed menu is opened it pushes down the page content.

I removed your javascript and called everything using [data attributes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) by adding the following to your nav-wrapper div:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
```

data-offset-top is the distance you need to scroll before the menu is affixed.

I also made one small change to your CSS:

```
#nav-wrapper.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a beautiful method

Answer (score 2):

It seems this can be achieved by replacing the CSS you provided by

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}

#nav.affix {
    top: 0;
}

#nav > .navbar-inner {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}
```

The main difference is that here, `#nav` covers both the cases `#nav.affix` and `#nav.affix-top`

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnPqF/10/).

edit:
The problem turns out to occur when `#nav`'s position is *inherited*. If you *fix* it, as I suggested, or if you set it to *relative*, as the other post suggested, your problem will be solved.

Comment: I like your explanation of the root cause for the drop down menu being below the page content