# Best method for implementing Bootstrap's affix-top function on nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get the affix-top function to work properly on my site I created using Bootstrap, but no matter what I set the offset as, it always prematurely jumps to the top of the page.  It should be noted, that when I view my page on a local view or in Firefox, everything acts as it should, with no violent jumps, but when I actually upload it to the server, and view it in anything but Firefox, that's when things get wonky.

Here is the HTML for my navbar:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="875">
  <div class="navbar-inner" data-spy="affix-top">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service-top">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-arrow">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!--/.nav-->
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse collapse pull-right-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
  </div><!--/.navbar-inner-->
</div><!--/#nav /.navbar navbar-inverse-->
```

Here's my JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
        $('#nav').affix({
            offset: $('#nav').position()
        });
    });
</script>
```

And some of my CSS that relates:

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
#nav {
    position:relative;
}
```

For what it's worth, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357576/bootstrap-menu-top-affix) is a similar post that I worked from first, but still couldn't get it to work for me.  [Here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/) is my site as well so you can see how the navbar is jumping around.

Thanks for any help.  I just can't seem to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like the best solution, but it works (for now).  All I did was change my JS code a little:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
        $('#nav').affix({
            offset: 675
        });
    });
</script>
```