# Bootstrap Affix fixed header after 100px making content jump

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm using Bootstrap Affix on my header and I want it to become fixed once the page is scrolled 100px. I have added in the jquery like so:

```
$('#navbar').affix({
      offset: {
        top: 100,
      }
    });
```

The problem is when I scroll the content on the page jumps up. I've added a wrapper with a min height but this doesn't solve the problem.

Can anyone help please?

Link to fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b5fusmsn/12/

Comment: Add `data-spy="affix"` to `navbar` and `padding-top` to `content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flicker/jump is because the navbar is changing from `position:static` to `postition:fixed`. When the affix is applied at 100px, which is close the height of the navbar 92px, it's always going to "jump" unless you had a [div of 100px in height above the navbar like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652581/bootstrap-affix-nav-causes-div-below-to-jump-up/20652911).

In your case, it looks like you're just trying to shrink the navbar padding after scrolling 100px, so in that case always keep the navbar postion:fixed and just adjust the padding when `.affix` is applied...

https://jsfiddle.net/etxyk0y1/1/

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 50px;
    z-index: 99998;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all .5s;
    top: 0;
}

.affix-top.navbar {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.affix.navbar {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f7f3;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Use the `nav-wrapper` to keep spacing between the fixed navbar and the content.

```
.nav-wrapper {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so others know this question is solved.